# Customize look of map with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

Is there a way to customize map colors using Google Maps for ExpressionEngine?

I know it can be done with Google Maps but since the plugin is generating the map code, I'm not sure how to add the code that controls map colors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us your current template code. Are you using an add-on?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an add-on. The add-on is Google Maps for EE as I mentioned in my post. The template code is `{exp:gmap:init id="map" class="gmap" style="width:100%;height:400px"}`

Comment: My bad. Read right past that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{exp:gmap:init id="map" class="gmap" styles="/assets/js/gmap-styles.js" style="width:100%;height:400px"}
```

[Download sample gmap-style.js](https://www.objectivehtml.com/assets/js/gmap-styles.js), edit it, and link to it using the `styles` parameter.

[See documentation](https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples/custom-map-styles).